# Bootstrap spans not working with full height sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive layout in bootstrap that has a full-height sidebar. I got the responsive part working, but the only problem is - the spacing of the spans don't seem to be playing well together.

On the right side - the main content - it doesn't span to fit the rest of the screen. Also, when the browser gets too small - the main content actually gets partially hidden by the sidebar.

Am I doing something wrong with the spans? If I remove the `position: absolute;` from the `.sidebar`, then the whole `.content.` piece slides underneath the sidebar - but the sidebar is no longer full height, and the content still doesn't fill the rest of the screen evenly. It seems as it's impossible to get this working correctly, but I want to use bootstrap for the convenience of not having to redo all the CSS/JS that's integrated.

Example:
[image: Spans not filling screen]
[image: Span partially hidden]

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3em 2em;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.sidebar .logo { margin-bottom: 3em; }

.content {
    margin: 5em;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Navigation for small screens -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse hidden-desktop">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="brand" href="/">Home Link</a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Navigation for larger screens -->
        <div class="span3 hidden-phone hidden-tablet">
            <div class="span3 sidebar">
                <div class="logo"><a class="logo-title" href="/">Home Link</a></div>

                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span9 content">

<div class="span5">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello. <small>This is.</small></h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris faucibus est vitae ante lobortis ultricies. Pellentesque blandit massa a velit convallis at accumsan elit gravida. Nulla facilisi. Fusce egestas consectetur velit vitae egestas. Cras vitae justo a sapien gravida condimentum. Donec lacinia lacinia ante. Proin eget est neque, ut egestas nibh. Donec non enim eu sem varius adipiscing. Proin dapibus enim a enim condimentum hendrerit. Donec vestibulum, mauris eget lobortis sagittis, enim libero dapibus augue, ac luctus ipsum augue quis purus. Aenean magna ante, elementum ac ultricies vitae, lobortis vitae augue. Nam metus erat, adipiscing posuere fringilla sit amet, molestie vel dolor. Quisque libero lacus, auctor eget porta vitae, vehicula eget mi. Vestibulum pulvinar hendrerit faucibus.

Aliquam scelerisque nisl sit amet mauris euismod bibendum. Phasellus ac laoreet enim. Praesent a felis id nisl ultrices dignissim. Nam dictum leo at quam vulputate mollis. Curabitur vitae ipsum enim, sit amet sollicitudin neque. Nunc iaculis ultricies convallis. Etiam nunc neque, consequat ac vehicula id, imperdiet in neque. Duis vitae sem magna. Nulla vehicula sapien sit amet sapien tempus tempus. Fusce pharetra dui nec risus sollicitudin vel pharetra arcu lacinia. Quisque eleifend sapien eu quam rutrum sed imperdiet nisi sagittis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque id placerat purus.</p>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Second Header. <small>Not working.</small></h1>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris faucibus est vitae ante lobortis ultricies. Pellentesque blandit massa a velit convallis at accumsan elit gravida. Nulla facilisi. Fusce egestas consectetur velit vitae egestas. Cras vitae justo a sapien gravida condimentum. Donec lacinia lacinia ante. Proin eget est neque, ut egestas nibh. Donec non enim eu sem varius adipiscing. Proin dapibus enim a enim condimentum hendrerit. Donec vestibulum, mauris eget lobortis sagittis, enim libero dapibus augue, ac luctus ipsum augue quis purus. Aenean magna ante, elementum ac ultricies vitae, lobortis vitae augue. Nam metus erat, adipiscing posuere fringilla sit amet, molestie vel dolor. Quisque libero lacus, auctor eget porta vitae, vehicula eget mi. Vestibulum pulvinar hendrerit faucibus.

    Aliquam scelerisque nisl sit amet mauris euismod bibendum. Phasellus ac laoreet enim. Praesent a felis id nisl ultrices dignissim. Nam dictum leo at quam vulputate mollis. Curabitur vitae ipsum enim, sit amet sollicitudin neque. Nunc iaculis ultricies convallis. Etiam nunc neque, consequat ac vehicula id, imperdiet in neque. Duis vitae sem magna. Nulla vehicula sapien sit amet sapien tempus tempus. Fusce pharetra dui nec risus sollicitudin vel pharetra arcu lacinia. Quisque eleifend sapien eu quam rutrum sed imperdiet nisi sagittis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque id placerat purus.</p>

</div>

        </div>
    </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already setting that sidebar to absolute, why bother with the `height: 100%`? It'd be easier to simply add `top:0; bottom:0`.

The reason your sidebar is getting slid over the content like that is the absolute positioning of the sidebar. If you want to keep that from happening, I'd recommend setting a defined width in your sidebar class (say, of `240px`), then changing content's CSS to read like so:

```
.content {
    padding: 5em;
    left: 240px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

That should constrain your content appropriately to not slide under your sidebar in any circumstance. Then, in order to make it appropriately responsive, adjust font size and width of your sidebar down as the screen reduces, and decrease the `left` property of `.content` to match the width of the sidebar.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you saying also set `.content` to `position: absolute;`? If I do that, the sidebar issue is gone but the content still doesn't stretch to the right of the screen for larger resolutions.

Comment: Yeah, you have to. Copy the CSS block as it's written in the answer and it should fill the remaining available space.

Comment: Ended up using `position: fixed;`. Made a few changes and didn't need the `overflow-y`, but I used the same idea. Thanks!